# P tag isn't showing

Tags: html

Super simple school assignment. I embedded an audio file and I'm suppose to add the transcript in a p tag following the audio file. No CSS required. Problem is, I can't get the text in my p tag to show up and I can't figure out why? I feel like I'm missing something really simple.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Edward Scissorhands</title>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Edward Scissorhands<h2>

<audio src="EdwardReview.mp3" controls>

    <p>Edward Scissorhands is a story set in a picturesque suburban town in the 1950s. 
    The story centers around protagonist Edward—a young man brought to life by the experiments 
    of his creator scientist. Edward was unfinished when his creator died, leaving him with 
    large scissor-like hands. He is then found by the local Avon-lady and adopted by her and her 
    family. The movie sees Edward attempting to navigate the peculiar social structures of an 
    exaggerated 1950s suburban landscape, while attempting to learn about life and love. Edward 
    Scissorhands is essentially a retelling of Frankenstein, through the lens of Tim Burton’s 
    magical storytelling. The scenery is captivating and the musical score really adds feeling to 
    the movie’s most moving scenes. The movie is set around Christmas time, so if you haven’t yet 
    seen it, what better time than this holiday season.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's your closing tag (</audio>) for <audio>? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Comment: I guess if you load that text in some web browser like Firefox and view the page source, the browser will indicate where the error is. After all, this is not a "we do your homework" service. You are expected to try significantly harder before asking the experts. You could also google for "html audio example". Hard to imaging there is none. See https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/HTML/Multimedia_und_Grafiken/audio&prev=search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Edward Scissorhands</title>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Edward Scissorhands<h2>

<audio controls>
  <source src="EdwardReview.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

    <p>Edward Scissorhands is a story set in a picturesque suburban town in the 1950s. 
    The story centers around protagonist Edward—a young man brought to life by the experiments 
    of his creator scientist. Edward was unfinished when his creator died, leaving him with 
    large scissor-like hands. He is then found by the local Avon-lady and adopted by her and her 
    family. The movie sees Edward attempting to navigate the peculiar social structures of an 
    exaggerated 1950s suburban landscape, while attempting to learn about life and love. Edward 
    Scissorhands is essentially a retelling of Frankenstein, through the lens of Tim Burton’s 
    magical storytelling. The scenery is captivating and the musical score really adds feeling to 
    the movie’s most moving scenes. The movie is set around Christmas time, so if you haven’t yet 
    seen it, what better time than this holiday season.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

You're not using the `audio` tag correctly. It needs to be in the format:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Because it is invalid, nothing below it is rendering correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have closing audio tag ,
Try this code!

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="school.mp3"   type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
```